# Some code highlighting which I cannot explain

Tags: visual-studio-code

For my code I often have to type #50, #100 etc

Some of these numbers are highlighted and I cannot find out why that is. At first I thought that is was done by the 8051 Assembly Language Support extension but it also occurs in C code (though I would not type these things in C). Today I found out that #128 is marked blue and it gets a blue color in the scrollbar.

Why are these numbers highlighted, where can I find the settings and how can I turn it off?
EDIT:
To answer the first comment

[image]

Comment: use command `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scope` to see what different scopes the numbers have

Comment: Perhaps, a color highlight type of extension?